# How to convert seconds to hours in x-axis with matlplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a series data from one day which has 86400 datapoints. I try to plot this in a picture using using matplotlib. However, I want to change the x-axis to be hours like 00:00 01:00.

Now my picture is: [image]

My code is as follows:

```
start = 0
end = 1 * 60 * 60 * 24
total_time = end - start

axis = np.arange(0, total_time)
xlim = np.arange(0, 60* 60 *24, 60*60*4)

pl.interactive(False)
pl.plot(axis, yxis)
pl.xticks(xlim)
pl.show(block=True)
```

How could i to change seconds to hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom labels for the x-axis, see [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html) for more information. In this case, you could simply change your current `plt.xticks(xlim)` to:

```
plt.xticks(xlim, ['00:00', '04:00', '08:00', '12:00', '16:00', '20:00'])
```

or better:

```
plt.xticks(xlim, [str(n).zfill(2) + ':00' for n in np.arange(0, 24, 4)])
```

The step size 4 can here be changed to whatever is wanted.